# $\varphi(x)=0$ for every continuous linear form implies that $x=0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(E,||~~||)$ a normed vector space and $x\in E$.

I want to show show that  $$\varphi(x)=0~~\forall\varphi\in E'\Rightarrow~~x=0$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $E'$? What is its relationship with $E$?

Comment: E is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, and E' is the space of continuous linear maps from E to $\mathbb{K}$,

Comment: Should the proposition you want to prove be restated as follows?

$$\exists A \subseteq E : x \in A \wedge \phi(x) = 0 ~ \forall \phi \in E' \Rightarrow 0 \in A$$

Comment: @DonnieDarko For the future: usually you should write about your own attempts of solving the problem in your question.

Comment: @supinf that what i do usualy, but this one it looks trivial but i cant prove it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done using the
[Hahn-Banach Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

**Some further hints**:
You start by defining a suitable linear functional on the linear hull that is spanned by $x$
(under the assumption that $x\neq 0$).
Then you can extend this linear functional to a functional in $E'$.

Comment: Yes sir .if we suppose that $x\neq 0$ then 
by a corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem there exists a continuous linear form $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)=||x||$ and $||\phi||=1$ hence the contradiction because $\phi(x)\neq 0$